# how to return value in subroutine in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm stuck with my ARM programming exercise.

This is my pseudo code

```
fun sum(int n):
    int res = 0
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++):
        res += i
    return res
fun main():
    register0 = sum(2)
```

and this is my code. I'm sorry that code is not text.

```
.text
.global _start
sum:
    push {r0-r2, lr}
    mov r1, #0 @ r1 = sum
    mov r2, #0 @ r2 = idx
loopSum:
    add r2, r2, #1
    add r1, r1, r2
    cmp r2, r0
    bne loopSum
    pop {r0-r2, pc}
_start:
    mov r0, #2 @ ro = n
    bl sum
    ldr r1, =result
    str r0, [r1]
end:
    mov r0, #0
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0
.data
    .align
result:  .word 0
.end
```

The Point is 'saving return value in r0'. But when i push and pop registers, values just disappear.

Is there any technique to return the value in specific register? Should i just write like this? I think there must be better way.

```
sum:
    push {r1-r3,lr}
    @ save value of r0 in r3 and complete the sum
    mov r0, r3 @ should i add this?
    pop {r1-r3, lr}
_start:
    mov r0, #2
    bl sum
    @ ...
```

===

I added push {r0-r2,lr} to practice how to use it.

And I learn why I use push and pop. It keeps the value before procedure called by put registers in stack. Right?
By the way, i change my code to return value at r0. Can you check it?

```
sum:
    push {r1-r3, lr}
    mov r3, r0 @ r3 = n
    mov r1, #0 @ r1 = sum
    mov r2, #0 @ r2 = idx
loopSum:
    add r2, r2, #1
    add r1, 1, r2
    cmp r2, r0
    bne loopSum
    mov r0, r1 @ return val of r3 to r0
    pop {r1-r3,pc}
```

I am just seizing how arm assembly works so never mind about pushing r1~r3,lr.

Comment: There is no reason to `push` and `pop` `r0`-`r3` as those are caller saved registers according to convention. Also since this is a leaf function you don't even need to put `lr` on the stack either.

Comment: You need to check the calling convention for your system. Usually, return values that fit into a register are simply stored into the first register (`r0`), bigger objects are stored into (stack) memory provided by the caller. If you only use the method yourself, you can also make up your own conventions.

Comment: @chtz thank you, i never notice calling convention. This is my first time for programming in low-level. Thx

Comment: "I'm sorry that code is not text" So are we. But it's not our problem, you need to fix it. Source code posted on SO should be in text format.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read [ask] and take our [tour].  I have downvoted your question because it contains a picture of code.  Please edit your question to replace the picture with code as text and I'll take back my downvote.

Comment: Don't even try to benchmark compare between C and assembly, and claim C to be hundreds of times faster: The compiler will most probably convert your C code to Gauss Summation.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is that when you do `pop {r0-r2, pc}`, the content of `r0` is overwritten.  As your code is not commented, I cannot tell why you were pushing and then popping `r0`, but perhaps you should just stop doing that to fix your code.

You only need to push those registers whose values you have to restore.  As you have not specified what your calling convention is, I cannot tell you which registers these are.  If you manage to find out what calling convention you use (is it the EABI?), please let me know so I can extend my answer.

However, as you want to return a value in `r0`, that register cannot possibly be one you need to restore, so simply change your `sum` function to

```
sum:
    push {r1, r2, lr}
    mov r1, #0 @ r1 = sum
    mov r2, #0 @ r2 = idx
loopSum:
    add r2, r2, #1
    add r1, r1, r2
    cmp r2, r0
    bne loopSum
    pop {r1, r2, pc}
```

and this problem should no longer occur.

Comment: I fix my code can you check it?

Comment: @hilaw00 Have you tested it for yourself?  Try to use a debugger and run the code with different inputs.   What happens if `n = 0` or `n = 1` is passed?

Comment: didn't check it. Maybe I should add some conditions. However I recognize mechanism of it super thanks.

Comment: @hilaw00 Try to do as much checking and debugging as possible before you ask a question.  I am always happy to help you, but I am not going to do all the leg work for you.

Comment: "Can you check it?" didn't mean "Can you debug it?":(
I'm new to low-level programming so i just wondered that "Is this the right way to return value at register 0 conventionally?".

Comment: @hilaw00 Ah, I see.  Yes, the idea is implemented correctly.  You just copy your return value to `r0` and then return from the function.  The return value is just whatever is in `r0` when the function returns.